# Replace all and only complete words from JS string (not nested words)

Tags: javascript, replace, nested, cpu-word

I want to replace words from text files uploaded by the user. So I don't know the exact structure of the text or which word(s) will be replaced.
The word(s) to replace, will be the word that shows up most amount of times in the users text.
But I found some issues with my current method which is using `.replace()` with `new RegExp()` to replace globally and case-insensitive (gi). This works.
**My issue is when a longer word or name contains the word that I want to replace.

Ex: I want to replace "is" with "xx" in the phrase "This is Isak".**
I want: "This xx Isak".
But I get: "Thxx xx xxak".
**So I tried replacing with " is " (to ignore any nestled words).

But that has it own issues.**
If that word shows up multiple times next to itself "is is is" then the result will be "xx is xx" instead of "xx xx xx". (Because of the second "is" not having a space on it's left side?)
Or if it is next to a dot or comma "That is, like this." the result will be: "That is, like this."
But I want: "That xx, like this."

I've searched stackoverflow and google but can only find answers to related questions but not how to solve this "nested word" problem.
Any ideas?

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
  // colors are only to make it clear for everyone what is replaced
  var str = "thisandthat, is, this is isak. Is it Isak is is is it?"
  var regexp = new RegExp(/is/, 'gi')
  // I tried finding and replacing with spaces to make sure I don't get the "is"-part of "this"
  // var regexp_withSpaces = new RegExp(/ is /, 'gi')
  // var replaceWith_withSpaces = ' <span style="color:blue">xx</span> '
  var replaceWith = '<span style="color:blue">xx</span>'
  var currentResult = str.replace(regexp, replaceWith)
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  '<b>Original text:</b><br>' +
  str +
  '<br><br><b>Current results:</b><br>' +
  currentResult
}

myFunction()

</script>
<!-- Next part is to show expected and actual results. -->
<!-- Colors only to show what parts are wrong and what parts are wanted. -->
<p style="margin-top: 4rem">
  <b style="color:red">A. Wrong results (with RegExp replace function):</b>
  <br>
  th<span style="color:red">xx</span>andthat, <span style="color:green">xx</span>, th<span style="color:red">xx</span> <span style="color:green">xx</span> <span style="color:red">xx</span>ak. <span style="color:green">xx</span> it <span style="color:red">xx</span>ak <span style="color:green">xx</span> <span style="color:green">xx</span> <span style="color:green">xx</span> it?
</p>

<p>
  <b style="color:red">B. Wrong results (with spaces in RegExp replace function):</b>
  <br>
  thisandthat, <span style="color:red">is</span>, this <span style="color:green">xx</span> isak. <span style="color:green">xx</span> it Isak <span style="color:green">xx</span> <span style="color:red">is</span> <span style="color:green">xx</span> it?
</p>

<p>
  <b style="color:green">Wanted results:</b>
  <br>
  thisandthat, is, this <span style="color:green">xx</span> isak. <span style="color:green">xx</span> it Isak <span style="color:green">xx</span> <span style="color:green">xx</span> <span style="color:green">xx</span> it?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a word boundary to make sure that you are replacing once a word and not a part of a word.

```
  ...
    function myFunction() {
  // colors are only to make it clear for everyone what is replaced
  let str = "thisandthat, is, this is isak. Is it Isak is is is it?"
  var regexp = new RegExp(/\bis\b/,'gi')
    ...
```

Comment: new RegExp(/\bis\b/,'gi') solves the issue! Big thanks @Karthik Radhakrishnan

Do you have any ideas how I should do if I want to replace a word that is in a variable?

`var replaceThisWord = "is"`and then want to use the RegExp for word boundary? Like: `new RegExp(/\b + replaceThisWord + \b/, 'gi')`

Comment: @philipdev, You can do it like this.
new RegExp('\\b'+replaceThisWord+ '\\b', 'gi')